# Excel formula with multiplication that increases by 1 for every column it is in

Tags: excel, excel-formula, autocomplete, autofill

I have a formula in one column

```
=IF(AND($B2+D2>2023,$B2+D2<=2122),($B2*2)+$A2,0)
```

and in the column beside it, the formula is

```
=IF(AND($B2+E2>2023,$B2+E2<=2122),($B2*3)+$A2,0)
```

I am hoping to modify the formula so that it automatically increases the multiplication value by 1 in every column I drag it over to.

I figured it would automatically increment, but when I dragged it over the ($B2*2) portion remained the same. I tried to add a dollar sign to see if that would work and the formula was incorrect. I have had to drag the formula over and change the multiplier manually, but there are many columns potentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use COLUMN() which returns a Long of the column index number:

```
($B2*COLUMN(B2))
```

so in the first cell put:

```
=IF(AND($B2+D2>2023,$B2+D2<=2122),($B2*COLUMN(B2))+$A2,0)
```

and drag it over.  The COLUMN reference will change and the multiplier will change as it is drug.  And no helper row is needed.

Comment: Should that be * for multiply instead of the x which  OP has put in?

Comment: @TomSharpe when I put in the  * in my original question it removed it in the post to show $B22 or $B23 so I changed it to x to try and give clarity. it is supposed to be * and not x

Comment: So if it is in the text you may have to escape the * with \ to avoid it being interpreted as a modifier for italic text, but if it is in a highlighted formula you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

Make yourself a helper row that is the multiplier.

So in the new `B2` you have a `2`. Make `C2` be `=B2+1`. Then copy that over your row. So that you have the multiplier sitting in a row.
then change your formula

```
=IF(AND($B3+D3>2023,$B3+D3<=2122),($B3xB$2)+$A3,0)
```

The `$` in front of a column or row says hold that constant over the copies. So B$2 means when you copy that to a new column, the B will change but the 2 will not. This will let you explicitly see the multiplier.

You could alternatively do this by computing distance from `B` directly in your formula or by using `COLUMN(B2)` as the "B$2" parameter in my code above and that will copy over just fine.

Comment: I have important information in column B so I cannot add the helper there. I suppose I could add the helper to an empty column and do the same thing, but it would add unnecessary information to the table. Thanks though

Comment: Yup, just use "COLUMN(B2)" for your multiplier instead. It computes the value "2" from the "B" and would get "3" from "C".